# Removing text styles in Sketch

Tags: json, sketchapp, textstyle

I had imported some text styles(JSON format) in my sketch file initially using "Shared text styles" plugin for sketch. Now I have a text style library that I have linked to my file. My problem is that I cannot seem to **get rid of the initial text styles from my sketch symbols menu**. I tried the text style organiser, but the original text styles(JSON ones) don't show up there. They only show up in my symbol override menu. I tried to edit the JSON of the entire sketch file and was able to remove the unwanted code, but when I save the file, sketch throws an error. Also, important thing, the file that i'm working on is linked to Abstract(version control tool)[unwanted text styles from B3 to Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGexT.png)
Any solution for doing this?